# kill spawn processes and stop for loop in bash

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that spawns other processes

**script1.sh**

```
for i in "${array[@]}"; do        
    ./script2.sh $i
done
```

the problem is that if I terminate script2.sh the subsequent scripts gets called in the for loop and there's no way to kill script1.sh and stop the for loop.

how do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [break](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_05.html),

```
for i in "${array[@]}"; do 
    if ! ./script2.sh $i ; then break ; fi
done
```

Comment: Have you tried that? `[.scirpt2.sh: No such file or directory`. Adding a space helps against the error, but does something else.

Comment: Yes; you are wright. Updated answer with use of exit code.

Comment: You can simply `if ! ./script2.sh $i ; then break ; fi`

Comment: @mpm: how does it work if I need to call script2.sh as a background process, ./script2.sh $i &, it gives a syntax error